# How to get SQL in Visual Studio c# project without installing SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing C# standalone client application which requires me to have a database/ and 2-3 tables and I don't want to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on client machine for a small piece of software?

Is there anything within Visual Studio I can use it and after installing I can use that database / tables without installing SQL Server 2008 R2 software on client?

Comment: Your project could use any kind of database with an ADO.NET provider. So SQLite, MS-Access, SQL Server Compact ...... are all good to go

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is SQL Server CE (Compact Edition)

This is not a standalone full fledged database server, but an embedded database which resides in your application folder.

You might want to read into some further information:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx

Comment: I don't need to install visual studio & SQL server right on client machine?

Comment: @RegisteredUser - you can deploy SQL CE either via a bootstrapper or you just drop the files in your app folder, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg213826.aspx

But please be avare, sql-ce has some (minor) limitations, see http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

Comment: Registered User: The only thing you need to make sure of, is that your compiled/deployed application contains all required assemblies and you're good to go.